# Sorting lists according to the order of another list in R

Tags: r

I have about 20 related lists of 2 (i.e. the elements in position n of each list are related). 
I now want to sort the values in each of the lists second list (dens) in ascending order and make the same changes to the other lists so that I still have right relation between the lists when finished.

**Example:**

```
list_1 <- list(a = c(44,47), dens = c(2331,1644))
list_2 <- list(a=66, dens= 1890)
list_3 <- list(a=c(44,46,48,50), dens=c(8000,1452,1596,7521))
mylist <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3)
names(mylist)<-c("ID_1","ID_2","ID_3")
```

**Needed result:**

> *ID_1:*
>
> $ a:  num [1:2] 47   44
>
> $ dens:  num[1:2] 1644 2331
>
> *ID_2:*
>
> $ a:  num    66
>
> $ dens:  num 1890
>
> *ID_3:*
>
> $ a:  num [1:4]   46   48   50   44
>
> $ dens:  num[1:4] 1452 1596 7521 8000

Well I would need a dynamic solution for different List lengths.
I have tried a few things but everything failed with messages like "not possible for lists" or "input has to be atomic/factor" etc.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use nested lapply calls with an ordering step at the inner level:

```
> newlist <- lapply(mylist, function(LL) {
               lapply(LL, function(col){ col[order(LL[['dens']]) ]})})
> newlist
$ID_1
$ID_1$a
[1] 47 44

$ID_1$dens
[1] 1644 2331


$ID_2
$ID_2$a
[1] 66

$ID_2$dens
[1] 1890


$ID_3
$ID_3$a
[1] 46 48 50 44

$ID_3$dens
[1] 1452 1596 7521 8000
```

Comment: `lapply(mylist, function(LL) lapply(LL, \`[\`, order(LL$dens)) )` would shorten it, at the cost of some interpretability.

Answer (score 3):

I would take it out of a `list`:

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(bind_rows, c(.id="id", mylist)) %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(dens)


     id     a  dens
  (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1  ID_1    47  1644
2  ID_1    44  2331
3  ID_2    66  1890
4  ID_3    46  1452
5  ID_3    48  1596
6  ID_3    50  7521
7  ID_3    44  8000
```

If you have vectors of the same length, I don't think there's any reason not to put them in a data.frame.

Comment: This should also be doable with the data.table package, but it's not working for me at the moment.

Comment: Interesting, data.table's `rbindlist` `idcol=` bit fails. It doesn't recursively look at the lengths of the lists within `mylist`.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah, I guess the problem is that `vapply(mylist, NROW, 0L)` is 2 (the number of vectors) instead of the proper lengths.

Comment: it means you need a pretty ugly solution, `listlen <- lengths(sapply(mylist,`[`, "dens")); cbind(rbindlist(mylist), ID=rep(seq_along(listlen), listlen) )[order(ID,dens),]` or something is the best I can come up with.

Comment: @thelatemail `rbindlist(lapply(mylist,setDT), id=TRUE)[order(.id,dens)]` works, but modifies `mylist`.